# How to compile c program into elf format?

Tags: c, linux, elf

I am new to Linux. I am trying to compile my c program into an elf file so I can use read elf to find information about the function,etc. Whenever I try to use the readelf with the output file (after compiling my c program), it says it is not an elf file. So how do I compile my C program so it compiles into an elf file. Or maybe I m not understanding? I am using gcc to compile

Here's my command line for compiling:

```
gcc -Wall main.c  a.out
```

and then readelf -a a

Ok, so I compiled it with gcc -o test -Wall main.c and it compiled with no errors and then did the readelf with : readelf -a test and it still says it's not an elf and when I do file it comes up with: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows, so whats's going on here?

Comment: please show your compilation command line

Comment: What format is it? Use the `file` command to print the file type.

Comment: If you're using Linux, and you're using a distribution that's less than 20 years old, you most certainly _should_ be getting ELF from the compiler.  Please edit the output of `file a.out` and `head -c 32 a.out | xxd` into the question, that will help us figure out what's going on.  (If you do not have `xxd`, try `hd` instead.)

Comment: gcc on linux will usually spit out ELFs by default. You don't have to do anything (object files are ELF, a.out is ELF, shared libs are ELF).

Comment: `gcc -Wall main.c  -o <new-name>`

Comment: Also, try just `gcc -Wall main.c`; if you put `a.out` on the command line as well it will do a thing that is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: You shouldn't put `a.out` on the command line, it creates that output file by default. You would use `-o filename` if you wanted to compile to a different filename.

Comment: `gcc -Wall main.c a.out`: beeep: `gcc -o a.out -Wall test.c`

Comment: `gcc -Wall main.c -o a.out && file a.out`  should tell you you've got an ELF.

Comment: Ok, so I compiled it with gcc -o test -Wall main.c and it compiled with no errors and then did the readelf with : readelf -a test and it still says it's not an elf and when I do file it comes up with: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows, so whats's going on here?

Answer (score 5):

Let's try it:

```
gcc -Wall test.c a.out
gcc: error: a.out: No such file or directory
```

that's a strong hint that something went wrong... So `gcc` doesn't produce any `a.out` file (and if the `a.out` file already exists, passing it like this tells gcc to try to compile it, and since it's not a valid text/c file, you'll get `a.out: file not recognized: File truncated` and it will end badly as well).

You need to specify the executable output with `-o` switch (if you need `a.out` on unix/linux, just *don't* type it)

```
gcc -Wall test.c
```

will create `a.out` executable (.elf) if no compilation error is found.

```
gcc -o myexe -Wall test.c
```

allows to change executable name.

EDIT: you're *not* running Linux but Cygwin (on *Windows*). That doesn't make the answer above invalid, but Cygwin is creating native *windows* executables, not `.elf` files. You cannot create `.elf` files using `gcc` there (unless you get a windows -> Linux cross-compiler if it exists)

`readelf` command is present in the Cygwin distro, but won't read programs compiled with `gcc`. It can analyze `.elf` files from Linux or other systems using that executable format, but certainly not Windows PE format.

Comment: Ok, so I compiled it with gcc -o  test -Wall main.c and it compiled with no errors and then did the readelf with : readelf -a test and it still says it's not an elf and when I do file it comes up with: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows, so whats's going on here?

Comment: can you run that? are you sure you're running linux? can you type `where gcc` and `which gcc` just to see? can you execute `./test` now (note: don't call executables `test`)

Comment: where gcc: C:\cygwin64\bin\gcc.exe (Cygwin 64 is the terminal I'm using), which gcc : /usr/bin/gcc       and yes, ./test executes

Comment: <facepalm>: you're not running Linux _at all_. Check my edit

Comment: guess I need a new professor lol, they said we were running Linux and we used Cygwin in class. Thanks for clarifying.